# How can I use Parse to send data to specific user

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm creating an online game which have to send data between users. I chose Parse as the backend service. How can I use Parse to do this task?

Comment: witch platform you are coding at?

Answer (score 0):

Query for the user that you want to send data to and send data

Comment: If you ask a more specific question with code that you tried , you will get more specific answers.

Comment: Could you tell how to send data, please code it for example.

Comment: Are you sending the data from one android device to another or some other method?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but form what I understand Yes, via TCP.

Comment: I am not very well versed with sockets so i cant help much , But if your using parse , you can send data in push messages from one device to another in json format , Basically put the data in json format , query the device that you want to send and send the data , Then the recieveing device must have a custom onRecieve method to extract the data and perform the required operations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the Parse Docs. What you want to do is documented very well there.

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

Take a look at saving and retrieving objects.

Also make sure your console (where you can see the "User" class and all your other classes) is set up with the objects you need.